# How to get child objects on condition in Django

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I`m trying to fetch data from the parents' model to the child model who fulfills the condition. I have a product model and there is also a product review model.
so I need to fetch records from a product model to reviews models that have a rating of 1.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    code = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    ...

class Review(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    ...
```

output:- from all product models get reviews who have a rating of 1.
like this MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM product_product as product INNER JOIN product_productreviews as review ON product.id = review.product_id WHERE review.rating = 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property (e.g. `reviews_with_rating_of_one`) to your `Product` model like below:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    @property
    def reviews_with_rating_of_one(self):
        return Review.objects.filter(product=self, rating=1)


class Review(models.Model):
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Note:** if you want to loop over all your products and access `reviews_with_rating_of_one` property, then the above solution is not very efficient, as it will make an additional database query for each product (to retrieve the reviews).
If all you want is all the reviews with `rating` equal to `1` and the details of the associated product, then the following should work for you:

```
Review.objects.select_related("product").filter(rating=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. here is one thing I forgot to mention that rating 1 is an example and it is not a fixed value for a query. it can be 1-5  with decimal no. and also I am trying fetching with the product model. i am trying with `Product.objects.filter(product_review__rating=1.0)`. but all reviews are coming in product model